# Join 3 tables in listview ado.net webapplication entity framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I am new to both ado.net and the entity framework. I am working on a web application with a login, and an administrator panel using ado.net, SQL server and the Entity Framework.

In the administrator panel, you should be able to create new users and change the role of the user (user, superuser or administrator).

I am working with the built in security tables, so there are basically 3 tables I need to show in a listview:

- Memberships (for the emailaddress)
- Users (for the username)
- Roles (to update the role)

I have generated the edmx schemes for the database, but I can't figure out how to show the data and allow updating.

For now, I was using the toolbox, inserting an entityDataSource for one table, inserting a listview with the toolbox, and giving it the data from the entityDataSource. This way I could do update/insert/delete on one table. But how to do this on multiple tables? I couldn't find any useful tutorials or anything, so any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use DynamicData together with your edmx.

However there is several tutorials on what you are trying to do

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-2

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/editing,-inserting,-and-deleting-data/an-overview-of-inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-cs

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/377291/An-Introduction-to-ASP-NET-Dynamic-Data-from-a-Beg

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but link 1 & 2 you posted are not for joining tables, that is what I've got already. As for link 3, I can't make anything out of it, too less detail for me to follow..

Comment: @Arnout check tutorials on master/details here http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/masterdetail/master-detail-filtering-with-a-dropdownlist-cs

Comment: thanks, but that's not really what I need. Actually, all I need to know is how to display 2 or more tables in one listview/datagrid with entity framework. I have dynamic data enabled now. Do I need to make an entity datasource for each of the tables? But how do I add 2 datasources to a listview/gridview?

Comment: @Arnout Tell me this, say you have table users and table roles. Do you want to display only selected user roles or all roles ?

Comment: @Arnout If you want tables to be independent, just add 2 data sources and 2 gridview, set each gridview.datasource to it's own datasource and you are done.

Comment: @Arnout if you want roles grid to be filtered by selected user, IT IS master-detail scenario , last link on tutorial i sent you for.

Comment: I don't want the 2 tables to be independent. Let's say I want to show each username with the role it has. So only the role the user is in should be shown

Comment: It's not that you are supposed to select a user and then you get the roles of the user. I want to show all the users with their role in a simple table (gridview/listview), that isn't master detail, right?

Comment: it depends. how many roles user could have? if many to many, are you going to show all user-role combination or all users ?

Comment: Let's say a user can only have one role. So many to one relation, a role can have many users but a user only can have one role. I want to display all users with their role

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30323/discussion-between-arnout-and-vittore)